# Multidimensional php array,create variable in text editor

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, text, editor

I was searching for about 1 hour for my question,found: absolutely nothing..
is there any solution for example for "Sublime Text" about helping to generate a variable of the array on that line currently where you're? 
for example:
i have an array

```
1. $array = [
2. 'option' =>[
3.   'option1' => [
4.       'option2' => [
5.       ]
6.     ]
7.   ]
8. ];
```

for example if i'm currently in the text editor on the line 4 this kind of helper should get me a variable in this case it should generate:

```
$array['option']['option1']['option2']
```

after that i just copy that line,and put in wherever i want to..
i want to say that i have big configuration files,reading all the massive from init to the actual key it makes life very hard..
so..is there any solution for that?I can't believe there is not a solution..
if not, then this would be very useful thing..

I appreciate your responses.. 
Thanks you all!